# How to run jenkins pipeline on all or some servers based

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline that copy file to a server. In job, i have defined 3 servers with the IPs.

What i need to achieve is that
A user can choose on which server to deploy the copy by typing yes or no under the **depoly_on_server_x**.

In my original pipeline, i'm using a list of IP - But the request is as I mentioned above
How can I define the request?

Thanks

```
server_1_IP - '1.1.1.1'
server_2_IP - '1.1.1.2'
server_3_IP - '1.1.1.3'

deploy_on_server_1 = 'yes'
deploy_on_server_2 = 'yes'
deploy_on_server_3 = 'no'



pipeline {
    agent { label 'client-1' }

    stages {
        stage('Connect to git') {
            steps {
                    git branch: 'xxxx', credentialsId: 'yyy', url: 'https://zzzz'
            }
        }
        stage ('Copy file') {
            when { deploy == yes }
            steps {
                dir('folder_a') {
                    file_copy(server_list)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def file_copy(list) {
    list.each { item ->
        sh "echo Copy file"
        sh "scp 11.txt user@${item}:/data/"
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a good bit easier if you interfaced and executed Ansible within the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using checkboxes instead?
You can use the [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) to create a checkbox list based on the server values, when the user builds the job he selects the relevant servers, this list of selected servers is propagated to the job with the selected values, which you can then use for your logic.
Something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'client-1' }
    parameters {
        extendedChoice(name: 'Servers', description: 'Select servers for deployment', multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
                type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: '1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2 ,1.1.1.3', visibleItemCount: 5)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Connect to git') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'xxxx', credentialsId: 'yyy', url: 'https://zzzz'
            }
        }
        stage ('Copy files') {
            steps {
                dir('folder_a') {
                    script{
                        params.Servers.split(',').each { server ->
                            sh "echo Copy file to ${server}"
                            sh "scp 11.txt user@${server}:/data/"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the UI it will look like:

[image]

You can also use a multi select select-list instead of checkboxes, or if you want to allow only a single value you can use radio buttons or a single select select-list.

If you want the user to see different values then those that will be used in the code it is also possible because you have the ability to manipulate the input value using groovy before using it.
For example if you want the user options to be `<Hostname>-<IP>` you can update the parameter value to be something like `value: 'server1-1.1.1.1,server2-2.2.2.2'`, then in your code extract the relevant ip from the given values:

```
script {
    params.Servers.split(',').each { item ->
        server = item.split('-').last()
        sh "echo Copy file to ${server}"
        sh "scp 11.txt user@${server}:/data/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow..Cool solution. I have one more question, Is it possible to include the server hostname? for example server1-1.1.1.  server2-2.2.2.2

Comment: @dzbeda Sure i have updated the answer with an example.